# Finding the day of week of a given date

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, datetime-format, dayofweek

I did a simple example in hackerrank.com which asks us to return the day of a given date. ex: If the date is 08 05 2015(month day year) it should return WEDNESDAY.

This is the code I wrote for this task

```
public static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
    String[] dates=new String[]{"SUNDAY","MONDAY","TUESDAY","WEDNESDAY","THURSDAY","FRIDAY","SATURDAY"};
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Integer.valueOf(year),Integer.valueOf(month),Integer.valueOf(day));
    int date_of_week=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return dates[date_of_week-1];
}
```

My code returns 'Saturday' for the given example which should be 'Wednesday'. For the current date which is 10 29 2017, it returns 'Wednesday'. 
Could anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you really have to use `Calendar` rather than the more modern `java.time` API? `LocalDate` is considerably nicer than this. (Also, it feels very odd to accept parameters in the order day/month/year rather than year/month/day; and why accept them as strings rather than integers? If the calling code only has strings, it can perform the parsing itself.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I tried LocalDate. It's better than using Calendar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you could use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and something like

```
public static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
    return LocalDate.of(
            Integer.parseInt(year),
            Integer.parseInt(month),
            Integer.parseInt(day)
    ).getDayOfWeek().toString();
}
```

Also, note that you describe the method as taking `month`, `day` and `year` but you implemented it taking `day`, `month` and `year` (make sure you are calling it correctly). I tested the above with

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getDay("05", "08", "2015"));
    System.out.println(getDay("29", "10", "2017"));
}
```

And I get (as expected)

```
WEDNESDAY
SUNDAY
```

If you can't use Java 8 (or just to fix your current solution), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) takes a `month` offset from `1` ([`Calendar#JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY) is `0`). So you would need (and prefer `parseInt` to `valueOf`, the first returns a primitive - the second an `Integer` instance) something like

```
public static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
    String[] dates = new String[] { "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", //
            "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY" };
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Integer.parseInt(year), //
            Integer.parseInt(month) - 1, // <-- add -1
            Integer.parseInt(day));
    int date_of_week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return dates[date_of_week - 1];
}
```

which gives the same result as above.

Comment: The last part is incorrect. See what year is printed by this -> https://ideone.com/8N5UQJ. The "offset from 1900" part is for `java.util.Date(int year, int month, int date)`

Comment: @Vasan Wow. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It worked. I added -1 to the 'month' parameter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `DayOfWeek::getDisplayName` will automatically localize the name of that `DayOfWeek` object.

Answer (score 2):

Month in `Calendar` is zero based in [cal.set(int,int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)). If I call your method with `getDay("29", "9", "2017")` it returns Sunday. So call your method with one less month i.e. 9, or call it with the Calendar constant for the month (`Calendar.OCTOBER`), or do `month+1` in the call to `cal.set`.

See this running demo: https://ideone.com/A6WGRJ. I also added a print of the date to confirm it prints the correct date.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I believe you're thinking of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Yes I added -1 to the month. Now it's working fine. Thanks.